# How to set shared memory size on aws job definition?

Tags: amazon-web-services, devops, amazon-ecs, aws-batch

I have an AWS job definition as a JSON file. And, I'm using the AWS CLI command to register the definition,
`aws --region us-east-2 batch register-job-definition --cli-input-json "file://jobdef.json"`

This is my jobdef.json content,

```
{
    "jobDefinitionName": "def1",
    "type": "container",
    "containerProperties": {
        "image": "<imageArn>",
        "vcpus": 4,
        "memory": 14500,
        "command": [],
        "jobRoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::<accountid>:role/<rolename>",
        "volumes": [],
        "environment": [],
        "mountPoints": [],
        "ulimits": [
            {
                "hardLimit": 500000,
                "name": "nofile",
                "softLimit": 200000
            }
        ],
        "resourceRequirements": [],
        "linuxParameters": {
          "sharedMemorySize": 2000
        }
    }
}
```

When I execute the register command, it throws an error `Unknown parameter in containerProperties.linuxParameters: "sharedMemorySize", must be one of: devices`

The [AWS document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ecs-taskdefinition-linuxparameters.html#cfn-ecs-taskdefinition-linuxparameters-sharedmemorysize) says the `sharedMemorySize` parameter is a part of `linuxParameters`.

The command works well without `linuxParameters`.

Could someone help me in registering a job definition with a shared memory size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By upgrading the awscli version the problem has been fixed. Previously I was using version `1.18` and now I have upgraded to `2.0`.